# rename columns of dataframe

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I have one dataframe that basically looks like this (contains data):

```
t <- data.frame(x1 = 1:5, x2 = 1:5, stingsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I have another dataframe that contains the original column names and a replacement for each

```
n <- data.frame(abb = c("x1", "x2"), erf = c("XX1", "XX2"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

What I would like to do is rename columns in dataframe t according to the specification in dataframe n. My problem is I can't figure out how to do that with map. Why is the following wrong:

```
map2_dfr(n$abb, n$erf, function(x, y) rename(t, !!y := x))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `rename_at`

```
library(dplyr)
t %>%
    rename_at(n$abb, ~ n$erf)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a one-liner in base R using `match`,

```
names(t) <- n$erf[match(names(t), n$abb)]
t
#  XX1 XX2
#1   1   1
#2   2   2
#3   3   3
#4   4   4
#5   5   5
```